# os.execv() - restart python script within itself

Tags: python

I have a simple python script to test the restarting functionality of os.execv():

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s:%(message)s')
file_handler = logging.FileHandler('jsontest.log', mode='w')
file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(file_handler)

count = 0
while count != 20:
    count += 1
    print(count)
    logger.info(f'the count is: {count}')
    print("continuing")

print('restarting')
time.sleep(60)
os.execv(sys.executable, ['python'] + sys.argv)
```

I should expect another set of 20 logs, a minute after the first, but those logs are not appearing and the log file is empty.

Am I missing something obvious about how this os.execv() function works when applied in this manner?

Comment: `sys.argv` already includes the executable name as the first element - but you're adding on another "python", so the command you're trying to execute is something like `python python script.py`.

Comment: @jasonharper: C-level `argv` would include that, but `sys.argv` actually doesn't. `sys.argv` includes the script name, but not the Python executable name.

Comment: To me, this sounds like a buffering issue.

Comment: The os.execv signature does require `os.execv(proc_name, [exec_to_run, *args])`, but the important thing to note is that the first argument is the name that the process will have.  The first argument of the list is the actual path to the executable.  So, I would try `os.execv('python', [sys.executable] + sys.argv)` to make sure that you are getting the right path to the executable.

Comment: @Malcolm you mean the actual unicode location of the .py file in place of 'python', correct?

Comment: I mean the full path as you will find in `sys.executable`, e.g. `/usr/bin/python3`.

Comment: @Malcolm so it would look something like 

```
os.execv(sys.executable, [sys.executable] + sys.argv)

```
I've tried that without success, meaning the log file is still empty indicating the script didn't actually restart.

Comment: I should have just tried the code.  It actually "works" for me.  Even with just `'python'` as the command since `python` is in my path.  My log file has entries in it.  The "problem" I see is that since each invocation opens `jsontest.log` in `w` mode it opens and truncates the file so there are only 20 lines in the file, but with every new invocation the timestamp is updated.  To get an accumulating log file change`mode='w'` to `mode='a'`

Comment: @Malcolm after changing the write mode to 'a' - I'm still not getting a new set of logs after the minute sleep.

Comment: Then I am perplexed.  Using your code as given with appropriate imports, the `mode='a'` for `mode='w'` replacement, and the `[sys.executable]` for `['python3']` replacement, it all works just fine for me.  Do you see the repeating stdout messages, or do they only print once as well?  Are you sure you are looking in the right place for the jsontest.log file? Perhaps your working directory isn't what you think it is.  Finally, what OS are you running under?  And back to imports you do have imports for logging, time, os, and sys, right?

Answer (score 1):

The following code with these changes

- require imports added
- `mode='w'` replaced with `mode='a'`
- `['python']` replaced with `[sys.executable]`
- the delay turned down to 10 seconds

works for me.

```
import logging
import time
import os
import sys

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s:%(message)s')
file_handler = logging.FileHandler('jsontest.log', mode='a')
file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(file_handler)

count = 0
while count != 20:
    count += 1
    print(count)
    logger.info(f'the count is: {count}')
    print("continuing")

print('restarting')
time.sleep(10)
os.execv(sys.executable, [sys.executable] + sys.argv)
```

It generates the following on stdout

```
p> python restartme blah blah
1
continuing
2
continuing
3
continuing
4
continuing
5
continuing
6
continuing
7
continuing
8
continuing
9
continuing
10
continuing
11
continuing
12
continuing
13
continuing
14
continuing
15
continuing
16
continuing
17
continuing
18
continuing
19
continuing
20
continuing
restarting
1
continuing
2
continuing
3
continuing
4
continuing
5
continuing
6
...
```

and the following in the jsontest.log file

```
2023-11-27 14:21:00,322:the count is: 1
2023-11-27 14:21:00,322:the count is: 2
2023-11-27 14:21:00,322:the count is: 3
2023-11-27 14:21:00,322:the count is: 4
2023-11-27 14:21:00,322:the count is: 5
2023-11-27 14:21:00,322:the count is: 6
2023-11-27 14:21:00,322:the count is: 7
2023-11-27 14:21:00,322:the count is: 8
2023-11-27 14:21:00,322:the count is: 9
2023-11-27 14:21:00,322:the count is: 10
2023-11-27 14:21:00,322:the count is: 11
2023-11-27 14:21:00,322:the count is: 12
2023-11-27 14:21:00,322:the count is: 13
2023-11-27 14:21:00,322:the count is: 14
2023-11-27 14:21:00,322:the count is: 15
2023-11-27 14:21:00,322:the count is: 16
2023-11-27 14:21:00,322:the count is: 17
2023-11-27 14:21:00,322:the count is: 18
2023-11-27 14:21:00,322:the count is: 19
2023-11-27 14:21:00,322:the count is: 20
2023-11-27 14:21:10,352:the count is: 1
2023-11-27 14:21:10,352:the count is: 2
2023-11-27 14:21:10,352:the count is: 3
2023-11-27 14:21:10,352:the count is: 4
2023-11-27 14:21:10,352:the count is: 5
2023-11-27 14:21:10,352:the count is: 6
...
```